# Why do I get Javax.servlet.ServletException?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jakarta-ee

In my application, I can create an application entity, however when I want to see all applications, I get the following error :

```
 The class 'io.undertow.servlet.spec.ServletContextImpl' does not have the property 'applicant'
```

I have other classes that are similar, but they work fine and I cannot figure out what is wrong here.

Referred line from the .xhtml:

```
<p:column filterBy="#{application.applicant.name}" sortBy="#{application.applicant.name}">
        <f:facet name="header">Name</f:facet>
        <p:cellEditor>
                <f:facet name="output">
                    <h:outputText value="#{application.applicant.name}" />
                </f:facet>
                <f:facet name="input">
                    <p:selectOneMenu value="#{application.applicant}" style="width:100%">
                        <f:selectItems value="#{applicantController.allApplicants}" var="s" itemLabel="#{s.name}" />
                    </p:selectOneMenu>
                </f:facet>
            </p:cellEditor>

</p:column>
```

The problem starts here:

```
<h:outputText value="#{application.applicant.name}" />
```

and everywhere I wrote "application.something" the problem occurs.

My last idea was that in Application.java, I wrote the following annotation:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Application")
public class Application {
```

..but in other classes the Table name starts with a lower case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [Mark Dzaebel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1337200/marc-dzaebel)'s comment I found the answer:

Application is an Expression Language implicit object. If you write application.something in your jsf page, **it tries to get the given property from this implicit object instead of your own Application.java entity.**

After I changed the datatable from

```
var="application"
```

to

```
var="apps"
```

it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

`\#application` resolves to an implicit Expression Language object that implements `ServletContext`. (See http://incepttechnologies.blogspot.com/p/jsf-implicit-objects.html). So this is not your Application entity. Programmatically, it's the same as `ExternalContext#getContext()` and exists since JSF 1.0

Comment: I was thinking about the same thing, but could not figure out why it is not the Application entity I created.